# Why is the Youtube API not displaying results for video IDs?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm new to basically all forms of programming, so forgive me if there's an obvious answer, but I was just trying to make a random video chooser by randomly adding characters to the Youtube API's search function under list, but when I run the API with either just id or id and snippet on, it shows this:

```
    {
     "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
     "etag": "\"i don't know if I can post my etag"",
     "regionCode": "CA",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 1,
      "resultsPerPage": 50
     },
     "items": [
     ]
    }
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know exactly what you have searched on but by the looks of the result there is just no results for your request.   YOu might want to try playing with the api here [search.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&_h=1&)

When you run it click Execute without OAuth not the authorize and execute button.  It will return a random list of videos.

You can use the q parameter to do a text search on videos for example that like toys.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked when I refreshed though, with the same search.